# Is my Laptop compatible for a dual boot?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

I have an asus laptop, windows 8 is the current OS. I am trying to install ubuntu as a dual boot, so far I have tried downloading it from the ubuntu website however a message error showed when I tried to reboot and now can't replicate this message, it said the file contained some sort of error. Next I tried to boot from USB, I don't have a cd drive so CD isn't an option. No luck with the USB it didn't recognize the files. Is there a possibility that my laptop isn't compatible with Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you change your boot settings?

Comment: I have an ASUS laptop works fine with dual boot. Link provided by Seth explains how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to visit [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) the answer is one which will take you through what you need to do to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download an ISO image of Ubuntu? You need to write it as a bootable image to the USB drive (you can't just copy the iso file onto the USB). Something like [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) will do it.

You may also need to change boot settings to boot from the USB drive (as @M.Tarun suggested). During boot, press Delete (or sometimes F2, sometimes other keys) to get into the BIOS. You should be able to select the USB drive as the boot device.

You may also need to turn off SecureBoot in the BIOS -- I'm not sure what the current status is of that, although I've heard Ubuntu were looking at getting their installers signed so it could be installed with SecureBoot turned on.